# C# Download a website with the content needed to display it properly

Tags: c#, web-crawler

following scenario: We've developed around 400 personal sites and we are currently trying to build our portfolio. Due to multiple reasons we would like to display the index so we can put it on our portfolio. First thought was to make programatically screenshots of every site. The heads in our company promptly debunked it because they want to show it live. Iframes are not an alternative apparently. So we have to download the index. Possibly only with the styles and images needed to display it properly.

I am unsure on how to start doing this.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: What kind of index are you talking about?

Comment: (I assume that index is the menu bar) If it are your own websites you could crawl the plain html code and look for a certain class/id that you put in the index area of every page. Take all code from the market div + the div definition itself. Pull all external resources (like the css file) and there you go, should work (although it is only for show, the links behind the index buttons will most likely be broken if they are dynamic, you also need to fix the link to the external files or thrust that the original website is still online)

Answer (score 0):

The underlying technology of CodedUI (and Selenium) uses a web crawler to isolate specific useful parts of a web page. I recommend using that underlying library to crawl your webpages running live, and extract whatever images and divs make up your page structure.

You can then emit these as static HTML to make page snapshots suitable for a site index.

Doing it this way means you will be using the same technology as you use for test automation, but instead of running tests, you can extract the useful structure from your HTML and emit it as a page snapshot. You will have to mark the "useful" parts of your HTML to enable the crawler to extract just the items you think should be indexed (i.e. include a data- property if HTML5). This might be a lot of work - so if you just need a screenshot of each of your pages, just use Selenium or CodedUI to crawl your sites and capture the screen image.